# Using a perl class object variables in destroy

Tags: perl

Can we access object variables inside the destroy method of a perl class.
For eg : i have a perl class as below:

```
package Person;

sub new {
   my $class = shift;
   my $self = {
      _firstName => shift,
      _lastName  => shift,
      _ssn       => shift,
   };
   # Print all the values just for clarification.
   print "First Name is $self->{_firstName}\n";
   print "Last Name is $self->{_lastName}\n";
   print "SSN is $self->{_ssn}\n";
   bless $self, $class;
   return $self;
}
```

I create my object like below:

```
$object = new Person( "Mohammad", "Saleem", 23234345);
```

How can I make destroy function so that it will print me like

```
detroying Mohammad
```

Comment: Have you actually tried it?

Comment: See the [documentation](https://perldoc.pl/perlobj#Destructors). Beware that in global destruction, other references may have already been destroyed at random.

Answer (score 3):

The [`DESTROY` method](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/DESTROY.html) gets the same `$self` reference as its first parameter as all other methods in Perl OOP.

```
package Person

sub new { ... }

sub DESTROY {
    my $self = shift;
    print "destroying $self->{_firstName}";
}

package main;
{
    my $foo = Person->new( 'foo', 'bar', 123 );
}
```

This will print

```
First Name is foo
Last Name is bar
SSN is 123
destroying foo
```